# Handle $_GET requests with Clean URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, clean-urls

I am have a clear URL based system so the categories will be shown like this

```
http://www.mysite.com/category/23/cat-name
```

Inside the categories page I have some sorting and pages options such as sorting by latests and lower price. Also, I have a pages navigation system

The problem is when the request is happening inside the page the `$_GET[]` doesn't show the variables I need. However it shows in the URL as

```
http://www.mysite.com/category/23/cat-name?page=3
```

The `$_GET` variable only shows the id of the category which is in our case now = `23` and ignored the page number which is in the url.

`.htaccess` content

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+)/[a-z][-a-z0-9]*$ cat.php?id=$1
```

Comment: `page=3` is it fixed? Or it should be `id=23`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the [QSA](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag at the end of your rule. This appends any existing query string to the one that you're constructing in the rule itself:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+)/[a-z][-a-z0-9]*$ cat.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So the rewritten URI should end up being: `/cat.php?id=23&page=3`

Answer (score 2):

Add QSA(query string append) at the end of your rewrite rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+)/[a-z][-a-z0-9]*$ cat.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query strings to be combined.

With the [QSA] flag, a request for /pages/123?one=two will be mapped to /page.php?page=123&one=two. Without the [QSA] flag, that same request will be mapped to /page.php?page=123 - that is, the existing query string will be discarded.