# How do we keep track of users' profiles on the web server in the real world?

Tags: php, html, profile

So far, I have always shown users their home page by simply getting the data from the database and creating their page on index.php, while if they went on other users' pages I used an HTTP get request( something like localhost/visit.php?id=123456)to get data of that particular user and show his/her page. But I'm noticing that in the real world, user's pages look something like localhost/id123456.
 How is this made possible? Is this a url manipulation using .htaccess?(I know only that I can reduce visit.php?id=123456 to visit?id=123456, but to just id123456 have no idea)
 Or does each user have its own php page(like id123456.php) on the server?(which seems to be very redundant)
So I'd really like to know how do they do this

Comment: Yes, it is manipulation using mod_rewrite and .htaccess.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755341/handle-get-requests-with-clean-urls - that question was specific to a certain situation involving rewritten URLs with GET parameters. This question is simply about how to rewrite URLs in general.